# Linked worker pools in Python

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, threadpool

I'm trying to setup a system of linked worker pools that look like this:

```
 ╭────────╮                  ╭─────────╮                  ╭─────────╮
 │        ├──> Worker 1 ───> │         ├──> Worker 3 ───> │         │
 │  Data  ├──> Worker 1 ───> │  Queue  ├──> Worker 3 ───> │  Queue  ├───> Output
 │        ├──> Worker 1 ───> │         ├──> Worker 3 ───> │         │
 ╰────────╯                  ╰─────────╯                  ╰─────────╯ 
 ╭────────╮                     ^ ^ ^
 │        ├──> Worker 2 ────────┘ │ │
 │  Data  ├──> Worker 2 ──────────┘ │
 │        ├──> Worker 2 ────────────┘
 ╰────────╯
```

Before I roll out my own generic solution, are there any existing libraries (or clean `multiprocessing` / `threading` examples) that I could use? I'm not sure what to call this sort of setup, so my Google searches haven't given me many useful results.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Is there any performance benefit of this structure of pools?

Comment: @NarendraPathai: I'm gathering data from multiple sources, processing it, and then writing it to disk. There doesn't really seem to be any other way of doing it.

Comment: are you writing the output to multiple files or a single one?

Comment: @NarendraPathai: It doesn't makes much of a difference. I'm just looking for a generic framework that lets me plug stuff together like this.

Comment: BTW looks like exactly the type of problem Go was created for.

Answer (score 1):

ZeroMQ is a lightweight solution and has Python bindings.
http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:python

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) before which is great at dealing with worker queues with multi processors being producer and/or consumers, saves having to worry about threading.

There's a Python client at [beanstalkc](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/)

Example taken from their wiki.

```
>>> import beanstalkc
>>> beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(host='localhost', port=14711)
>>> beanstalk.put('hey!')
1
>>> job = beanstalk.reserve()
>>> job.body
'hey!'
>>> job.delete()
```

This might suite your needs - IIRC you can have durable queues as well.